# JFreeChart making JFrame unresponsive?

Tags: java, swing, swt, jfreechart

When I create a JFrame, I am unable to interact with it. I can't resize it or click the title buttons, although I am able to move the window. Even something as simplistic as:

```
JFrame win = new JFrame();
win.setVisible(true);
```

will exhibit the problem. This is displayed in the console when the application is started:

```
2015-03-17 10:06:47.261 java[1406:507] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2015-03-17 10:06:47.261 java[1406:507] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
```

Apparently this can happen when mixing Swing and SWT components. I don't use the SWT library, although my project does use JFreeChart, which contains `swtgraphics2d.jar`. Is there any way to fix this while still using JFreeChart?

Comment: Show context of creating `JFrame`.

Comment: It happens even when I create the JFrame in an otherwise empty main().

Comment: do you use `javax.swing.JFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away when I removed the (now known to be) unnecessary jars, including `swtgraphics2d.jar`.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but you may want to check your classpath; I have no problem with `java -cp jfreechart/lib/*:… `, which includes `jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to create a `ChartPanel` with your `JFreeChart` and `add()` it to the `JFrame`. The default position is `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which should let your chart resize with the frame.

```
private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    YourDataset data = createYourDataset(…);
    JFreeChart chart = createYourChart(…);
    f.add(new ChartPanel(chart);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, be sure to start on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new YourClass().display();
        }
    });
}
```